# Permission denied while trying to write into app-specific files | Android 33

Tags: java, android

I've been developing an app for about two months now but recently I've encountered a problem while trying to create, write and read files on my app specific files directory.

I'm creating files and writing on them just as showed in [this](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific) Android Developers guide example but my app keeps getting the following exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Permission denied
at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:317)
at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1006)
at com.adoc.apktest.Tools.writeFile(Tools.java:36)
at com.adoc.apktest.GeneralFunctions.testCallLog(GeneralFunctions.java:71)
at com.adoc.apktest.Tests.run(Tests.java:98)
```

In the article I've mentioned before says:

> Your app doesn't require any system permissions to read and write to files in these directories.

So I can't figure out why this exception is thrown every time I try to create and write into a file.

Here's the code related to this issue:

MainActivity.java:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
...
        String testID = getIntent().getStringExtra("testID");
        Tools tools = new Tools(this);
        Tests tests = new Tests(testID, this, tools);
        tests.start();
```

Tests.java

```
    public Tests(String testID, Context context, Tools tools) {
        this.testID = testID;
        this.context = context;
        this.tools = tools;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();

        try {
            switch (testID) {
...
            case "generalFunctions": {
                    GeneralFunctions.testCallLog(context, tools, "016");
...
```

GeneralFunctions.java

```
public static void testCallLog(Context context, Tools tools, String number) {
        try {
            tools.deleteFile("pcStatus.txt");
            while (!tools.readFile("pcStatus.txt").equals("id=" + number)) {
                Log.w("General Functions", "pcStatus.txt not found");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            tools.deleteFile("status.txt");

            Log.i("Call Log Test (" + number + ")", "Number to call: " + number);
            Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            call.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));

            context.startActivity(call);

            tools.writeFile("status.txt", "endCall", false);
...
```

Tools.java

```
public void writeFile(String fileName, String content, boolean append) {
        File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), fileName);

        try {
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(content.getBytes());
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("Write File", "File: " + file.getAbsoluteFile() + "\nwritten successfully with data: " + content);
    }
```

Comment: You are just using the File class to create an empty file. That is not needed as openFileOutput will create the file if it does not exist and also delete an existing one and then create a new one. So start with removing this File and createNewFile stuff.

Comment: Further you are not using the append parameter.

Comment: I tried removing those lines and I get a FileNotFound exception:
`Failed to chmod(/data/user/0/com.adoc.apktest/files): android.system.ErrnoException: chmod failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)`

Comment: Chmod() ? Where are you calling that? This does not match your code. And you do that on a directory? This is not on a file.

Comment: `Log.i("Write File", "File: " + file.getAbsoluteFile() + "\nwritten successfully with data: " + content);
    }` You blindly write that. There could have been an IOException. Move this line to the right place.

Comment: No I'm not doing it on a directory, it's just the first line of the error, it goes like this:
`Failed to chmod(/data/user/0/com.adoc.apktest/files): android.system.ErrnoException: chmod failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.adoc.apktest/files/status.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
...`
It is just too long to put it all here

Comment: I asked you if you called chmod() yourself. You did not answer.

Comment: Sorry, no I did not, I don't really know why it shows up like that, I don't even use at all in the app :/

Comment: I never saw such a message. Strange. Try with a different file name to avoid issues with the old one. Apply all changes to code i suggested.

Comment: I've already tried with multiple names and applying your sugestions but none seems to fix it, thanks for your time and effort anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realised that deleting the app-specifig *files* folder will fix the issue:

```
/data/user/0/<package_name>/files/
```

Answer (score 0):

This helper class of mine helps you to handle app internal files:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * <b style="color: red;">This class is designed to work with Android 33.</b>
 * <br>
 * The private app internal storage files are located in the directory <b><code>getFilesDir()</code></b>.
 * <br>
 * <b>Alle files are stored and loaded in UTF-8.</b>
 *
 * @author David Weber
 */
public class AppInternalStorageHelper {

    /**
     * Checks if a file exists in the <b>app internal storage</b>.
     *
     * @return True if the file exists.
     */
    public static boolean fileExists(
            Context context,
            String filename) {

        return new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename).exists();
    }

    /**
     * Gets the path of the file with the given file name in the <b>app internal storage</b>.
     *
     * @return The file path of the file as String if the file exists, otherwise null.
     */
    public static String getPathOfFile(
            Context context,
            String filename) {

        File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename);
        return file.exists() ? file.getPath() : null;
    }

    /**
     * Creates and writes a file into the <b>app internal storage</b>.
     *
     * @return The created file.
     */
    public static File createFile(
            Context context,
            String filename,
            String fileContentAsString,
            boolean overwriteExistingFile)
            throws IOException {

        File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename);
        if (overwriteExistingFile) {
            Files.deleteIfExists(file.toPath());
        }

        return Files.write(file.toPath(), fileContentAsString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), StandardOpenOption.CREATE).toFile();
    }

    /**
     * Creates and writes a file into the <b>app internal storage</b>.
     */
    public static void createFile(
            Context context,
            String filename,
            Bitmap fileContentAsBitmap,
            Bitmap.CompressFormat fileFormat)
            throws IOException {

        File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename);
        OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
        fileContentAsBitmap.compress(fileFormat, 100, os);
        os.close();
    }

    /**
     * Reads the content of a file from the <b>app internal storage</b> into bytes.
     */
    public static byte[] readFileToBytes(
            Context context,
            String filename)
            throws IOException {

        File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename);
        return Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
    }

    /**
     * Reads the content of a file from the <b>app internal storage</b> into a <code>String</code>.
     */
    public static String readFileToString(
            Context context,
            String filename)
            throws IOException {

        return new String(readFileToBytes(context, filename), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }

    /**
     * Reads the content of a file from the <b>app internal storage</b> into a <code>List</code> of lines.
     */
    public static List<String> readFileToLines(
            Context context,
            String filename)
            throws IOException {

        File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename);
        return Files.readAllLines(file.toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }

    /**
     * Deletes all files in the complete <b>app internal storage</b> whose file names begin with the given prefix.
     */
    public static void deleteFilesWithPrefix(
            Context context,
            String filePrefix) {

        ArrayList<File> filesToDelete = new ArrayList<>(AppInternalStorageHelper.findFilesWithPrefix(
                context.getFilesDir(),
                filePrefix));
        for (File file : filesToDelete) {
            //noinspection ResultOfMethodCallIgnored
            file.delete();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Finds all files in the complete <b>app internal storage</b> whose file names begin with the given prefix.
     */
    public static ArrayList<File> findFilesWithPrefix(
            File dir,
            String filePrefix) {

        ArrayList<File> filesToReturn = new ArrayList<>();
        File[] listedFiles = dir.listFiles();
        if (listedFiles != null) {
            for (File listedFile : listedFiles) {
                if (listedFile.isDirectory()) {
                    findFilesWithPrefix(listedFile, filePrefix);
                } else {
                    if (listedFile.getName().startsWith(filePrefix)) {
                        filesToReturn.add(listedFile);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return filesToReturn;
    }

}
```